# Can Azure Active Directory allow dynamic URL endpoints

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have an application configured with Azure AD where I can redirect properly to my application.  However, part of the URL often contains an XSRF token.  In my AD application, I have my domain configured as https://m2.loc/admin. However, the URL that is generated as the return URL is something like https://m2.loc/admin/index/key/afaeb9db4b6ccb836eb89e529a26849e5884d3776e3b20c0b.  Is there a way that I can have some kind of a wildcard in the AD redirect URL or do I need to scrub the URL of the token before I can authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

In my testing ,it seems currently Azure AD supports that . For example : I use "https://m2.loc/admin" as redirect url in portal , then "https://m2.loc/admin" or "https://m2.loc/admin/index/key/xxxxx" also works(could get the access token) , using implicit flow , it will redirect to "https://m2.loc/admin/index/key/xxxxx#access_token=" .

Not sure when Azure AD change the behavior , you could directly set "https://m2.loc/admin" as redirect url in portal , and try "https://m2.loc/admin/index/key/" with dynamic value as redirect url in token request and check whether it works.

Comment: That's what I was expecting, too, but when I go directly from the non-keyed URL, I can properly redirected back to the application.  But when I use a keyed URL I get the error

`Additional technical information:
Correlation ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Timestamp: 2017-04-20 00:43:50Z
AADSTS50011: The reply address 'https://m2.loc/admin/admin/dashboard/index/key/afaeb9db4b6ccb836eb89e529776e3b20c0bdb673437b3849f0/' does not match the reply addresses configured for the application: 'xxxxxxxxxx'. More details: not specified`

Comment: It works on my side , please provide more details which could help me reproduce that error . Also please refer to [this document](http://paulryan.com.au/2016/azure-ad-app-wildcard-reply-url/) and check whether wildcards works in your scenario .

Comment: That doc also says it's allowed, but not supported and may go away with a few of the comments saying the same thing as me.  When I try to save a wildcard URL I get `Your URL must be in a valid URL format, begin with https://, and be limited to 255 characters in length`.  Remove the * and it saves.